# Non-nested double seasonality using dshw() in R

Tags: r, forecasting, decomposition, stl-decomposition

I'm trying to use dshw() to deal with double seasonality -- in my case, daily data with one-week (7-day) and one-year (365-day) seasonality.  However, I get the following error when I run my code:

```
data<-msts(1:1000, seasonal.periods=c(7,365), ts.frequency=365, start=2012)
decompose<-dshw(data, period1=7, period2=365)
 -- Error in dshw(data, period1 = 7, period2 = 365) : Seasonal periods are not nested
```

What do you think is the best practice to get around this issue?  Should I just use stl twice on my data (for 7 and 365 day frequencies)? Or modify the data in some way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `tbats()` model instead. It was specifically designed to avoid this problem. DSHW is a special case of a TBATS model.

```
decompose <- tbats(data)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using tbats, but am having a similar issue to this CrossValidate post -- http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55716/interpreting-time-series-decomposition-using-tbats-from-r-forecast-package -- how do I interpret the slope and level series produced by the decomposition?

Comment: Thanks. So, to combine them for forecasting, can I think of slope like "trend" in an stl decomposition?

Comment: Also, I don't see tbats as an option in hierarchical forecasting package `hts` -- any thoughts on how to incorporate it for one of the time series in a hierarchy?

Comment: Please spend some time reading the package documentation provided. Use the combinef function to combine ANY forecasts.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll test out tbats and combinef.

Answer (score 0):

If you define period2 in terms of period1 then you won't get the error.

Instead of:

decompose<-dshw(data, period1=7, period2=365)

use:

decompose<-dshw(data, period1=7, period2=7*52)